# Trying to get data from a php page that fetch a json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I'm trying to get the data I fetch using PHP.

the page is named twitter-fetch.php

now what I know is, that page is now filled with json data converted to associative array because I json_decode() on the the data. (please correct me if I'm wrong).

now what I'm trying to do is calling that page using ajax.

the name of the project is phone. the my js file is in the js folder. and the twitter-fetch.php is in php folder. I just want to see the result in console for now, help... frowning

I'm still new to ajax and json so I'm really not sure on what I'm doing here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/phone/php/twitter-fetch.php',
        type:'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            alert('success!');
        }
    });
});
```

this the php line where I used the json_decode and stored it in $string

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?q=%23forsale&result_type=recent&count=100';
//the TwitterAPIExchange is a PHP Wrapper that I used
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings); 

$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
```

UPDATE:----- $.getJson

```
$.getJSON('./php/twitter-fetch.php',function(result){
            var output = $.map(result, function(item, index){
                var listitem = $('<li></li>');
                $('<h2>'+item.user.name+'</h2>').appendTo(listitem);
                return listitem;
                console.log(listitem);
            });
            $('#js-result-list').html(output);
        });
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: Are you getting success message?

Comment: I'm not getting anything...

Comment: Add an error handler an check the textStatus and errorThrown properties - see "error" on the jQuery.ajax page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: hi @ron thanks for the reply, got the error [Error:parsererror SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Array"]. I don't understand this.. what should I do?

Comment: try removing json_decode(...) from the PHP. Your JS content-type specifies JSON to be returned.

Comment: now my index is filled with objects, because I included twitter-fetch.php. should I remove that include in the index? btw I got an error "Error:parsererror SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'"

Comment: @rontornambe if I change the dataType: to "jsonp". I get this error "Error:parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"

Comment: jsonp is for cross domain restFul interfaces. Try removing both the contentType and dataType entries. It seems you are receiving string, not JSON data and you are not passing JSON either.

Comment: You are very welcome, but more importantly do you understand why it works?

Comment: @rontornmambe lol not really, maybe I will get it if you can explain me what is the difference between $.ajax and $getJson. Now I'm trying to output the data to html. I read a lot of things about this, I thought php is somehow similar to js, but no... I updated my post so you can see my getjson code.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're sending a request to the link `[website directory]/phone/php/twitter-fetch.php` which probably isn't a real file. Instead, you need to go back to the `phone/` directory using `../` and then put `php/twitter-fetch.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/twitter-fetch.php',
        type:'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            alert('success!');
        }
    });
});
```

Also, remember when you put `/` at the beginning of a relative link, that relative link gets appended to the website directory. If you want it to be appended to the lowest directory the current file is in, don't put `/` at the beginning.

Comment: hi @Noble thanks for the reply, that gave me an error though. instead I used this ./ , what about my php code? I know json_decode converts a json data into an associative array. now I tried echoing $string. I'm still not getting anything in the console.

Comment: I'm not a PHP person (Python FTW), but I do know a bit of PHP and your PHP looks good to me. Are you getting a PHP error or a JavaScript error? If the former, someone else'll have to help you.